# Get most recent N files and delete the rest

Tags: c#, file-io

I am trying to write a method that gets files from a folder, orders it by creation time, takes the top five latest files and deletes the rest.

Any help will be much appreciated, my code that i have is as follows:

```
DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryPath);
FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var x = FileList.OrderByDescending(file => file .CreationTime).Take(5);
```

How do I amend this code to delete all the other files?

Comment: What's wrong with the two lines of code you've got? Why did you keep all the commented-out code?

Comment: It was trail and error code. The two lines of code is fine, i get the top 5 files, but how do i delete the rest of the files (excluding the top 5 the i got)?

Comment: I edited the post a bit; if I got the tags incorrect, please fix them -- or add more tags, if more are appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are keeping the first `N` and doing something else with the rest, it would be better to just loop through everything, throwing the first `N` into a separate list while calling `Delete()` on the rest.

```
var query = fileList.OrderByDescending(file => file.CreationTime);
var keepers = new List<FileInfo>();
var i = 0;
foreach (var file in query)
{
    if (i++ < N)
    {
        keepers.Add(file);
    }
    else
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryPath);
var query = directory.GetFiles("*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in query.OrderByDescending(file => file.CreationTime).Skip(1))
{
    file.Delete();
}
```

Comment: Could you please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263601/windows-phone-8-1-implement-virtualization-for-custom-variable-sized-gridview?