# Deleting files base on time creation

Tags: c#, delete-file

I found this code at: [Get most recent N files and delete the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060174/get-most-recent-n-files-and-delete-the-rest)

Error Encounted: The name 'fileList' does not exist in the current context

How can I set the folder directory I want the code to read from?

```
var query = fileList.OrderByDescending(file => file.CreationTime);
var keepers = new List<FileInfo>();
var i = 0;
foreach (var file in query) {
    if (i++ < N)
    {
        keepers.Add(file);
    }
    else
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable comes from the code in the question. You don't have it in your code.

Comment: ok, i get i now.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is clear in the example from where you have taken the code that fileList is a array of FileInfo. you have to declare and fill that array before code.:

```
DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryPath);
FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```