# Windows phone 8.1 Implement virtualization for Custom variable sized Gridview

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, out-of-memory, virtualization, wrappanel, staggered-gridview

I have implemented custom itempanel for gridview to support variable item height using this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76fcebbd-53f5-4433-b415-1f3b64cc2e1c/how-to-get-gridview-with-variable-sized-gridview-items?forum=winappswithcsharp) posted by JerryNixon.My Custom panel supports 3 different sized template(depending on image dimension I am deciding which template to use).This custom Gridview should have pagination and it should support more than 200 items. Right now i could load only 50 items and it crashes because of out of memory exception event in **1GB device**. Its one of the requirement in out project. I know when we implement custom itemspanel it losses default virtualization.

I have checked [Pin.it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/pinit/9nblggh187vr) app. They have implemented variable sized Gridview template and performance is very good, i could load more than 200 items.

Is there any way i can implement virtualization for my custom items panel? I have no idea how we can implement virtualization.**If anyone has implemented it please give us some ideas how to get started with this so that it will help us a lot.**

I dont think wrappanel code is required to post. If its required i ll post it.

Please give some suggestions. It will be very helpful :). Thanks :)

Comment: Are you displaing image in gridview items?

Comment: Yes.. Itemtemplate mainly has image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we implemented virtualized custom grdiview by referring to the code posted in [this](https://windevgo.wordpress.com/2013/08/10/virtualize-the-variablesizedwrapgrid/) link. Code given in the link is for virtualizing horizontal gridview. I changed the code a bit to change it to vertical gridview. Many thanks to the person who posted the code. It helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

To overcome out of memory exception just reduce the  pixel width of the images and you will save the memory so that more items can be loaded in the page.

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" Width="150" Height="170">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding MainImage}" DecodePixelWidth="400"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
```

The above code does the trick.

Comment: I do know this. When we give DecodePixelWidth less than what image already has. Image will be blurred. I want actual virtualization to be implemented,like reusing the views. Because microsoft is not providing this